# __FILE__ is deprecated and will be removed in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have this line of code

```
NSLog("\(__FILE__)  \(__LINE__)  \(__COLUMN__)  \(__FUNCTION__)")
```

I updated to xcode 7.3 and I now get a warning that states that this method has been deprecated and will be removed in swift 3.

I tried changing the code to

```
NSLog("\(#file)  \(#line)  \(#column)  \(#function)")
```

but I still get the same warning. What is causing this?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question I fear @Jojodmo . And after replacing it with print , nothing changes.

Comment: That's why I posted a comment - it was only a guess. Good luck! :)

Comment: First, do a clean build (hold option and choose Product > Clean Build Folder, then Product > Build). If you still get the error, you're using `__FILE__` somewhere else in your project.

Comment: Well , i restarted the project and built the code after cleaning the build folder and it worked .. thank you for your suggestions @robmayoff

Comment: If that solved your problem, you should post an answer to your own question, and accept it so others can find this easier

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with print and maybe wrap it into a public funciton:

`public func superLog(_ fileName: String, definition: String, lineNumber: Int, variable: String, value: Any) {
let fn = fileName.replacingOccurrences(of:"/Users/userName/Documents/IOS/project/", with: "")
print("\n \(fn)  \(lineNumber)\n \(definition)\n\n(variable)\n➳",value,"\n")
}
superLog(#file, definition: "log", lineNumber: #line, variable: "var", value: value)`

Comment: Please edit your code, there are a bunch of non-ascii characters and the indentation is all wrong.